# Android compose animation float equality test

Tags: android, android-animation, android-compose

I am trying a simple project with android jetpack compose. I have an animated float state (using `animateFloatAsState`) which goes from 0 to 1, something like this:

```
var xTarget by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0F) }

val x: Float by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = xTarget,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = xDuration, easing = xEasing),
        label = "x animation",
    ) {
        x -> when (x) {
           0 -> xTarget = 1
           1 -> xTarget = 0
        }
    }
```

with a button triggering the animation by setting `xTarget = 1`. Now I want to react when x = 0.5, something like this:

```
 if (x == 0.5) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Middle")
```

But I find that this is unreliable - it does not execute on all of the runs - which might be expected since we are dealing with equality of an animated float.

What do you think is the best way to deal with this?

I can think of two ways off the top of my head: 1) test a small interval instead - but this is not ideal since the cutoff between being unreliable and giving lots of hits is sharp and dependent on the speed of the animation. And 2) something like

```
var isRightTested : Boolean by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

if (x>0.5 && !isRightTested || x < 0.5 && isRightTested) { 
        isRightTested = !isRightTested
        // TODO
}
```

which seems way too convoluted (edit - it is now much more concise, see my comment below).

Comment: After editing my second solution (2) above to something much more concise (see the current question) I do find that it works quite well, so perhaps that is the best way. But it would nevertheless be interesting to see what other people make of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this if you need it for x:

```
var xTarget by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0F) }

val x: Float by animateFloatAsState(
    targetValue = xTarget,
    animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = xDuration, easing = xEasing),
    label = "x animation",
) {
    x -> when (x) {
       0 -> xTarget = 1
       0.5 -> xTarget = 0.5   // add this line for 0.5
       1 -> xTarget = 0
       in 0f..0.5f -> xTarget = 1   // add this if you need a range (0f - 0.5f)
    }
}
```

you can also add these in when statement in xEasing if you need to make your animation jump up/down

---

I see you are changing xTarget to 1 when x is 0 and to 0 when x is 1. If you want an infinte animation you can also use something like this:

```
val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "")
val alpha by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
    initialValue = 1.0f, targetValue = 0.0f, animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
        animation = keyframes {
            durationMillis = 3000
            0.0f at 0 with LinearOutSlowInEasing   // or your custom easing
            1.0f at 500 with LinearOutSlowInEasing
            0.0f at 1000 with LinearOutSlowInEasing
            1.0f at 1500 with LinearOutSlowInEasing
            0.0f at 2000 with LinearOutSlowInEasing
            1.0f at 2500 with LinearOutSlowInEasing
            0.0f at 3000 with LinearOutSlowInEasing
        },
        repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart,
    ), label = ""
)
```

The code above will give you blinking behavior something like cursor. And it will keep repeating every 3000ms

Comment: Hi thanks again. Your first code isn't quite what I want since the final lambda - as you know - is an onCompleteListener and so won't trigger on x = 0.5 if the xTarget keeps switching between 0 and 1. I can potentially use some adaptation of it so thanks anyway. Your second code block is really interesting - I hadn't come across the keyframes class before. Is there a way to stop/pause/start the infiniteTransition? If not, is there a framework which has keyframes and also stop/start options?

Comment: yeah, you're right about the lambda. I don't think there is really a way to start/stop the infiniteTransaction. I can be wrong. One workaround can be done is to add/remove/visible/invisible the view from the screen.

Comment: OK thanks. Yes I guess moving it to its own composable which returns the float and then creating/destroying that composable seems a sensible way to proceed, minimising unnecessary recompositions of other components and also able to cancel it easily.